# Finding the number of factors using a while loop

Tags: factors

so i have this method that finds the number of factors of a given number. It works fine and everything but i am using a for loop and my teacher is wanting me to change it into a while loop to make it more efficient, ive tried to change it but i keep getting endless loop here is the code i have using a for loop what might be a good to change it to a while loop without using a break and only having one return statement in the whole method

```
 public static int numberOfFactors(int num){
  int i;
  int total=0;
 for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
   if(num%i==0)
        total++;
 }
  return (total);}
```

Comment: then show what have you done with the while loop :)

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're using, but in several compiled languages for and while loops end up having the same bytecode.

Comment: Not sure if this is for a comp sci class or a mathematics class, but there are some properties of numbers that would help you to make your algorithm more efficient. For instance, if num%P==0 and num%Q==0, then num%(P*Q)==0 for all (P*Q)<=(num/2).

Comment: its for my data structures class comp sci pretty much but this actually helps thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see how:

```
i = 1;
while(i <= num) {
    // do things
    i++;
}
```

Is any more efficient than:

```
for( i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    // do things
}
```

As far as I can tell? It's not! I'd love to know why your teacher thinks it is.

---

That said, here's what you can do to make it more efficient:

- Calculate the square root of `num` and put it in `sqrtnum` as an integer, rounded down.
- Change your loop to `for(i=1; i<sqrtnum; i++)` (note `<`, not `<=`)
- If `num%i==0`, increment `total` by `2`, instead of `1`.
- After the loop, check if `sqrtnum*sqrtnum == num` - if so, increment `total` by `1`.

In this way, you only have to loop through a fraction of the numbers ;)

Comment: I would agree that it's OP's algorithm that is inefficient, not his/her choice of loop structure.

Comment: yeah i dont know why my teacher was telling me all this he is real anal bout doing it his way and stuff

Comment: If he were my teacher, I'd turn in a code that consists of an array, mapping integer keys to the number of factors as a value, actually hardcoded with values all the way up to a thousand, and have the code do something like [PanicSort](http://xkcd.com/1185/) for input higher than 1,000 :D

Answer (score 0):

Not any more efficient but....

```
public static int numberOfFactors(int num) {
  int total = 0;
  int i = 1;

  while(i <= num) {
    if(num%i == 0)
      total++;
    i++;
  }

  return total;
}
```